# How to add details to a Stack Overflow question

Tags: discussion, specific-question

I use these services a lot, but still, I have a question.

When I ask something, *[Apache Syncope modify @XmlElement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53558056/apache-syncope-modify-xmlelement/53562458#53562458)* and after an answer, I think I have to add more details (in the example I suppose help to clarify if I add all the content of the class RestResponse) I don't know exactly how I have to do it.

Must I add a comment, answer my own question, or edit the first question?

Comment: A bit of research can do wonders.  I suspect you can make that question a lot more to the point by first googling "apache syncope choose between xml and json payloads"

Comment: Thanks Hans, I supousse you are talking about the question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53558056/apache-syncope-modify-xmlelement/53562458#53562458. Please, if you can help me say in this question. I still can't solve it.

Comment: Stop rolling back the question

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You should edit your question.

Stack Overflow is *not* a forum where you hold a conversation with people.

There are questions and there are answers to questions. There are also comments where people can ask for clarification etc.

If people leave comments telling you that your question isn't clear or is lacking details then you edit that information into the question. You can then flag those comments as "no longer needed".

Then, hopefully, you'll get answers.